# Angular HostListener on click remove text selection

Tags: angular, click

I'm struggling to understand why text selection (using mouse) got deleted automatically on HostListener click.

I built a very basic directive to detect if user click on a link in a paragraph and add some logic to it. However, it stops user from selecting a text (copy/paste) as it automatically deselect the text.

Any thoughts?

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: any) {
    if (event.view.getSelection().type !== 'Range') {
      alert('you clicked');
    } else {
      alert('U selected text');
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you ctrl + click vs just clicking? It sounds like it is your browser deselecting your text and selecting the link. You may have to save the text in a variable if you want to access it when you click something else.

Comment: click & ctrl+click are both fine as it is fired click event normally. However, only when you use mouse to select the text on element binded to above attribute directive which somehow Angular de-select the text.